# Restoring iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, windows, restore

I need to restore my iPhone (I use iTunes on Windows 7). I backed-up the backup in `MobileSync/Backup` to an external drive (thankfully).

Now I have a long, nonsensically named folder containing the backup files, but when I try to move that directory back into the `MobileSync/Backup` directory, it isn't showing an available backup to restore on my local system.

Directory structure:
   C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming\AppleComputer\MobileSync\Backup\d0474d7f055ed768a337d83f611c26cf6f9517a7\d0474d7f055ed768a337d83f611c26cf6f9517a7\

Any help is mucho appreciated, I think this is mostly a directory structure issue.

Comment: Maybe some metadata are missing? Also, you sure you typed `MobileSync/Backup` right? Windows has backslashes to separate directories, you typer a forward slash twice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work or not, but you could try this: Firstly, delete all backups from iTunes. Quit iTunes. Then locate the iTunes backup folder `/Backup` and delete that. Then copy your backup to that location. Open iTunes and see if the backup is there again. If not, delete the backup location again. Make a new backup. Then replace the backup file from the one in your external drive.
If this doesn't work and no other suggestions work you might want to consider checking the apple forums/support website if someone has asked a similar question. If not, maybe ask there as well.
You could also try taking your iPhone and the back-up in to an Apple Store if you have AppleCare. Not sure if they would help you or not if you don't have AppleCare.